# How to fade out element of array?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have an array of strings and I'm trying to animate each one as a `Text` view on the screen, one at a time.

I am making something that:

- Iterates through the array
- Creates a `Text` view that animates in (with opacity and a slight position change)
- Waits for a little while so you can read the text
- Fades out with an opacity

I did just that with this code:

```
Group {
    let dialogue = [
        "string1",
        "string2",
        "string3",
        "string4",
        "string5",
        "string6"
    ]
    
    ForEach(0..<dialogue.count, id: \.self) { index in
        Text("\(dialogue[index])")
            .frame(width: geometryProxy.size.width * 0.25, height: geometryProxy.size.width * 0.25, alignment: .center)
            .minimumScaleFactor(0.15)
            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
            .foregroundStyle(.white)
            .font(.system(size: 25, weight: .medium, design: .serif))
            .background(.cyan.opacity(0.5))
            .opacity(hasPresentedDialogue ? 1 : 0)
            .offset(y: hasPresentedDialogue ? 0 : geometryProxy.size.height * 0.35 - geometryProxy.size.height * 0.375)
            .position(x: geometryProxy.size.width * 0.65, y: geometryProxy.size.height * 0.35)
            .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.75).delay(5 * Double(index)), value: hasPresentedDialogue)
    }
    .onAppear { withAnimation { hasPresentedDialogue.toggle() } }
}
```

Well... almost just that. I cannot figure out how to get the views to fade out before the next one comes. Right now, they're all just piling up on top of each other, which is obviously not ideal.

How can I make each element also fade out before the next element comes along?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a wrong concept for showing dialog one after another. As you are showing them inside a `ForEach` loop so it will appear all in a once.

I have omitted your custom designing but sharing the concept of showing each text once and moving to the next text after a certain amount of delay. Hope you can infer your answer and add your custom designs later on.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    let dialogue = [
        "string1",
        "string2",
        "string3",
        "string4",
        "string5",
        "string6"
    ]
    
    let delay = 2 // 2 seconds
    @State var currentDialogIndex = 0

    var body: some View {
        Text(dialogue[currentDialogIndex])
            .font(.title)
            .onAppear(perform: {
                Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: TimeInterval(delay), repeats: true) { _ in
                    withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: TimeInterval(delay))) {
                        currentDialogIndex += 1
                        if currentDialogIndex >= dialogue.count {
                            currentDialogIndex = 0
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I got it to work, but I cannot figure out how to make each one move down as an offset. Only the first one moves down.

Answer (score 1):

A `PhaseAnimator` can be used for this kind of staggered presentation:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    let dialogue = [
        "string1",
        "string2",
        "string3",
        "string4",
        "string5",
        "string6"
    ]

    @State private var hasPresentedDialogue = false

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometryProxy in
            let w = geometryProxy.size.width
            let h = geometryProxy.size.height

            PhaseAnimator(dialogue, trigger: hasPresentedDialogue) { string in
                Group { // needed for transitions to work
                    Text(string)
                        .frame(width: w * 0.25, height: w * 0.25)
                        .minimumScaleFactor(0.15)
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                        .foregroundStyle(.white)
                        .font(.system(size: 25, weight: .medium, design: .serif))
                        .background(.cyan.opacity(0.5))
                        .id(string) // needed for transitions to work
                        .transition(
                            .asymmetric(
                                insertion: .push(from: .top),
                                removal: .opacity
                            )
                        )
                }
            } animation: { _ in
                .easeInOut(duration: 0.75).delay(1) // delay(5)
            }
            .padding(.leading, w * 0.525)
            .padding(.top, (h * 0.35) - (w * 0.125))
            .onAppear { hasPresentedDialogue.toggle() }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Animation]

If you try the code above you will find it doesn't start and stop as neatly as in the gif. That's because `PhaseAnimator` works in its own special way:

- The initial phase starts as showing, even before the trigger is triggered.
- At the end of the cycle it goes back to the first phase.

To fix it for recording the gif, I used a blank string at the start of the array. Inside the closure I used an if statement to check for an empty string:

```swift
Group {
    if !string.isEmpty {
        // content as before
    }
}
```

This way, the first phase can be completely suppressed. If you choose to use the same approach, you might want to suppress the delay associated with the animation too (for the first phase only).

Other ways of addressing the "return to start" can be found as answers to the post [How to use PhaseAnimator to create animations that doesn't loop back to the first phase?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77414418/20386264).

Comment: This sounds like a really great option too, I will look into it. Thank you.